# R: self-starting function SSasymp with known parameter?

Tags: r, nls

I want to fit an asymptotic model as follow:

y(x) = Asym + (R0 - Asym) * exp(-exp(lrc) * x)

The model could be fitted in R using nls() function:

```
y <- c(22.180,21.941,21.786,21.724,20.964,19.128,18.371,17.508,16.931)
x <- c(1,3,5,9,18,36,72,144,288)

nls(y ~ SSasymp(x, Asym, R0, lrc))
```

However, if I know the value of R0 (for example R0 = 25), then how can I fit this model with the self-starting function SSasymp?

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to specify the model function explicitly, and then fit the model using sensible starting values:

```
f <- function(x, Asym, lrc, R0 = 25)
    Asym + (R0 - Asym) * exp(-exp(lrc) * x)
nls(
    y ~ f(x, Asym, lrc),
    data = data.frame(x, y),
    start = list(Asym = 15, lrc = -3))
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: y ~ f(x, Asym, lrc)
#   data: data.frame(x, y)
#  Asym    lrc
#17.965 -2.526
# residual sum-of-squares: 12.32
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 16
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.565e-06
```

One way to choose sensible starting values is to use estimates for `Asym` and `lrc` from the unconstrained fit `nls(y ~ SSasymp(x, Asym, R0, lrc))`.

So for example:

```
# Unconstrained fit
fit <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(x, Asym, R0, lrc))
coef(fit)
#Asym        R0       lrc
#17.057226 22.361817 -3.877708

# Constrained fit with R0 = 25 and starting values from fit
nls(
    y ~ f(x, Asym, lrc),
    data = data.frame(x, y),
    start = as.list(coef(fit)[c(1, 3)]))
```

Comment: Thank you @Maurits! This is a solution. But it may be not very efficient when I have many groups of data to be fitted.

Comment: @Lin *"But it may be not very efficient when I have many groups of data to be fitted."* On the contrary. This can be automated very nicely: Start with an unconstrained fit, then use relevant coefficient estimates as starting values for a constrained fit. Wrap it in a function. Done.